# WCF restful service is not available access under HTTPS (ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, https

I have work WCF service (over win.service). Service works through HTTP, but when i switch config to HTTPS then i get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

I have already learned a lot of information about this problem, but did not solve it.

Help please! :)

My service

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
    public interface IViberService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                    UriTemplate = "GetData")]
        Task GetData();


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
               UriTemplate = "Init")]
        Task Init();
    }

    public class ViberService : IViberService
    {   public async Task Init()
        {
           ....
        }

        public async Task GetData()
        {
          ....
        }
    }
```

My config serviceModel

```
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://......Service.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITelegramService"
                contract="......ITelegramService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITelegramService" />
        </client>
      <services>
        <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model  
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->

        <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ViberService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="ViberServiceBehavior" >
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="https://localhost:8001/ServiceModelSamples/ViberService"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address=""
                    binding="webHttpBinding"
   contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.IViberService" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBindingConfig"/>
          <endpoint address="mex"
                    binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITelegramService">
            <security mode="Transport" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
          <binding name="WebHttpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="Transport"/>
          </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="webBehavior">
            <webHttp  />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ViberServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="false"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Thank you in advance!

The same code works fine under HTPP

UPD: I use data from context in GetData.

```
string _data = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();
```

Maybe problem in this

Comment: https is not just alone configuration ,certiifcates is involved.

Comment: @HameedSyed This means that i need to issue a certificate for the service and configure the service for it?

Comment: Yes and also configure your code to handle https also.Some insite that can be applied to WCF http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-tutorial-for-beginners.html